# What are Some Ways or Common Methods to Tell if an Unsupervised Learning Algorithm is Correct

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, verification, unsupervised-learning

I know that part of the beauty, mystery, and complexity of unsupervised learning is that it extracts information out of lots of data that humans can figure out. However, are there any ways of knowing if the algorithm is right. For example, say it is looking at stock trends and it makes some deduction about a certain stock. Without actually seeing how it plays out, is there any way of knowing that it is right? The data it trained off of could be wrong or, more importantly, your algorithm could've just drawn the wrong conclusions. Obviously there are mathematical measures such as loss, but currently do we just have to live with the fact that the algorithm may be wrong? What are some of the ways that we can measure how correct an unsupervised learning algorithm is (or is "correct" just an ambitious term)?

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is too broad. If you need a 100% correct algorithm, machine learning is usually not the thing you'd use. So, roughly speaking, it's all about using some math measure and accepting that it might be wrong (how would you know that it's right if there's no way to find the actual answer?).

Answer (score 1):

In short:

> Without actually seeing how it plays out, is there any way of knowing that it is right?

No. If there was, then you wouldn't even need your original algorithm. Just make random predictions and use your oracle to tell if they're right or not.

> The data it trained off of could be wrong

ML algorithms learn based on data. If it's wrong, they will learn wrong. If you were only ever told that 1+1=3, would you have any reason to question it?

> more importantly, your algorithm could've just drawn the wrong conclusions

No conclusion is wrong if it is supported by the data. It might not be the one you're after (see https://www.jefftk.com/p/detecting-tanks), in which case you should get data that better describes what you're after.

> but currently do we just have to live with the fact that the algorithm may be wrong?

Yes, and we probably always will. Are humans ever always right about something? You could be wrong about very basic things under the right circumstances. And we're much smarter than current AIs.

> What are some of the ways that we can measure how correct an unsupervised learning algorithm is (or is "correct" just an ambitious term)?

It's very ambitious. You could check the results manually, if you're good enough at the problem you're trying to solve. If you want to classify images into dogs and cats, that's probably simple enough for you as a human to judge. Apply the algorithm and check some of the predictions manually to get an idea of how well it did.

If you want to have something that plays Go really well, challenge the world champion.

It depends on the problem.